# PHP set parent class property works but subsequent if statement doesn't

Tags: php, oop

I am building a genetics calculator, and have reduced my code to a simple format to explain my issue.

I basically have this line which instantiates a hatch object:

```
$hatch = new Hatch($maleGeneticsPOST, $femaleGeneticsPOST, 'leopardGecko', true);
```

This takes a form post for the parent genetics and sets the species type. Below is my Parent class and Child class to show how this essentially works:

```
class Genetics
{
    public $species = '';
    public $dominants = [];
    public $recessives = [];
    public $snows = [];
    public $wildtypes = [];

    function __construct($species)
    {
        $this->species = $species;
        echo $species; // returns leopardGecko as expected
    }
}

class Hatch extends Genetics
{
    function __construct($father, $mother, $species, $autoHatch = true, $hatchMethod = "punnett")
    {
        parent::__construct($species);
        // Other code for $father, $mother etc.
    }
}
```

On the face of it, those 2 classes are working well with each other, I can set the species type in the object and `Hatch` will set the parent to it.

However, what I am struggling to do is to then use the `$species` property in the parent to set the genetics, based off of the species selected/set; here's an example:

```
class Genetics
{
    public $species = '';
    public $dominants = [];
    public $recessives = [];
    public $snows = [];
    public $wildtypes = [];

    function __construct($species)
    {
        $this->species = $species;
        echo $species; // returns leopardGecko as expected

        if($species === "leopardGecko"){
            $this->dominants = ['NN', 'BB', 'TT'];
            $this->recessives = ['Bb', 'Tt', 'Rr'];
            $this->snows = ['Mm', 'Gg'];
            $this->wildtypes = ['QQ', 'Qq'];
        }
    }
}
```

And when I try and use them further down in my Hatch class, they just return empty arrays:

```
foreach ($alleles as $allele) {
    //echo $this->allGenetics[$allele].' ';
    if (in_array($allele, $this->dominants, true)) {
        //echo $this->allGenetics[$allele].' ';
        array_push($geckoGenetics['Gecko']['Dominants'], $this->allGenetics[$allele]);
        array_push($geckoGenetics['Gene']['Dominants'], $allele);
    } elseif (in_array($allele, $this->recessives, true)) {
        //echo $this->allGenetics[$allele].' ';
        array_push($geckoGenetics['Gecko']['Recessives'], $this->allGenetics[$allele]);
        array_push($geckoGenetics['Gene']['Recessives'], $allele);
    } elseif (in_array($allele, $this->wildtypes, true)) {
        //echo $this->allGenetics[$allele].' ';
        array_push($geckoGenetics['Gecko']['Wildtypes'], $this->allGenetics[$allele]);
        array_push($geckoGenetics['Gecko']['Recessives'], $this->allGenetics[$allele]);
        array_push($geckoGenetics['Gene']['Wildtypes'], $allele);
        array_push($geckoGenetics['Gene']['Recessives'], $allele);
    } elseif (in_array($allele, $this->snows, true)) {
        array_push($geckoGenetics['Gecko']['Snows'], $this->allGenetics[$allele]);
        array_push($geckoGenetics['Gene']['Snows'], $allele);
    }
}
```

***Please note***: The rest of that code works fine, I'm just talking about the `$this->dominants`, `$this->recessives`, `$this->wildtypes` & `$this->snows` variables - they return empty.

Am I missing something obvious? This is my first *proper* go at OOP and it's going well, apart from this bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'There is a difference in how you're calling the field `$species` and how you're trying to do so with `$dominants`. If you want to access fields outside of the scope of your function, you'll need to call them using `$this->`.

So in the constructor, if you replace the following:

```
public $dominants = ['NN', 'BB', 'TT'];
public $recessives = ['Bb', 'Tt', 'Rr'];
public $snows = ['Mm', 'Gg];
public $wildtypes = ['QQ', 'Qq'];
```

with:

```
$this->dominants = ['NN', 'BB', 'TT'];
$this->recessives = ['Bb', 'Tt', 'Rr'];
$this->snows = ['Mm', 'Gg'];
$this->wildtypes = ['QQ', 'Qq'];
```

It should work.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I still get `Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )` as the output

Comment: I ran the code and also noticed a string that wasn't closed in `$this->snows` (the string that contains "Gg"). For the rest it seems to work.

Comment: Hmm, I must be having some more issues down the line as it's not bringing down the genes at all. I'll check some more

Comment: Okay it looks like I'm having some inheritance issues down the stack but this answer fixed an initial problem so thank you :)